# convert 2D table into 1D table in C

Tags: c

In my program I have got a NxN table stored in one-dimensional table.
So, I use 
`#define Board(x,y) board[(x)*N + (y)]` and works perfectly

So, what if my board becomes N1xN2 and N1 is different than N2?
How should I set the #define instruction then?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't work perfectly.  You need `(board[(x)*N+(y)])` for square boards, and `(board[(x)*N2+(y)])` for non-square boards, assuming x from 0 to N1-1, y from 0 to N2-1